# docker IIS container locks up

Tags: docker

I am trying to follow the instructions [to run an IIS container](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/) 
I am a total newbie so I might be missing a step.

I am using WIndows 10 Pro with Docker for Windows set to Windows.

Docker is Version 17.06.0-ce-win18 (12627)
Channel: stable
d9b6651

I downloaded the image and then ran

```
Docker run 30
```

where 30 was my container

The container seems to have locked up showing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is followed by [issue 44](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/issues/44)

> Latest version of `microsoft/iis' image produces following output to container logs. This was not the case on previous versions

So:

- check if the error persists when using microsoft/iis:nanoserver-10.0.14393.1198 instead of :latest
- the issue mentions: " Currently trying to work around this issue by using [`SPINNER`](https://github.com/Ticketmaster/spinner) instead of `servicemonitor`"

Comment: I had a nanoserver image from 8 weeks ago , when I run it it , it locks up with no message.

Comment: @kirsteng OK, you can add that to the issue, but do mention you exact OS and docker version